# How to run post deploy script using hooks in aws elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run a script after my application is deployed on AWS. But whenever I try to run the script after deployment it gives a permission error.

> [RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error:
> Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/99_start_script.sh failed with
> error fork/exec .platform/hooks/postdeploy/99_start_script.sh:
> permission denied

I tried to include chmod +x command in my .config file but it gives no such directory error.

**script.config**

```
commands:
  01_chmod:chmod +x .platform/hooks/postdeploy/99_start_script.sh
```

**cfn.init**

> 2020-11-28 14:13:17,374 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD
> FAILED!------------------------ 2020-11-28 14:13:17,374 [ERROR]
> Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_chmod failed Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in
>
> worklog.build(metadata, configSets)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
> 129, in build
> Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
> 530, in build
> self.run_config(config, worklog)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
> 542, in run_config
> CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py",
> line 260, in build
> changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py",
> line 117, in apply
> raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name) ToolError: Command 01_chmod failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands in [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) run in root folder, not your application folder:

> By default, commands run in **the root directory**. To run commands from another directory, use the cwd option.

Also:

> The **commands run before** the application and web server are set up and the **application version file is extracted**.

Thus, even if you fix the execution folder, it will probably still not work because your application is not yet extracted. To run commands after extraction, use [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands).

Comment: Hello Marcin.Thanks for responding. I tried the container commands too. But it fails too when my instance gets terminated on overload and a new instance is created then the new instance runs the container commands and hence the script before the app is deployed. I want the command to be run after app is deployed because the script requires the application folder to run it.

Comment: @AnshulSingh You shoudn't need to use `chmod +x` on the EB instance. Usually you would do this on your local workstation or build stage before you pack your app into zip and upload to EB.

Comment: Alright but what about the script running before the application folder is created on the new instance. The script throws folder doesn't exist error.

Comment: @AnshulSingh Not sure what you mean. In your question there is no error about folder missing. Seems like a new issue, thus new question can be asked.

Comment: The container commands run on the new scaled up instance before the application is extracted into it. But I want them to run after the application is extracted into the new scaled up instance.